# Fabric Crashlytics with angular web app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-fabric

I am already using Fabric/Crashlytics for my smartphones application, and I would like to know if it is possible to plug an angular webapp to Fabric/Crashlytics? And if it is possible how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Fabric is only for mobile platforms.